# Low or no cost hosting option for web app that server-side checks another website and notifies users when a download is available?

Tags: firebase, aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions, hosting, web-hosting

I am a newbie to building web applications. I would like to build an app that will asynchronously check another website link to see if a file is posted. There is a file posted every day at an undetermined time, to a link corresponding to the day. If the file has not been posted, the link returns a 404. When the file is posted, the web app should notify all users.

What hosting services might be best suited for this? It will need to support authentication for users, and also the server side file link checking functionality. I was exploring Firebase Cloud Functions but I'm not sure how I would schedule a function to check the file link asynchronously throughout the day.

Any suggestions would be well appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "I would schedule a function to check the file link asynchronously throughout the day." => have a look at [scheduled Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase seems like a perfect fit for your needs. You can use one of Firebase's authentication providers to manage your authentication needs, and then use this in your security rules or cloud functions to control access.

Additionally, as Renaud stated in the comments, you can use [scheduled functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) to check the other site periodically throughout the day. I would set up a pub/sub that checks every x minutes (can be as frequent as once per minute) and then process this data however you'd like. Perhaps write to a document in Firestore that your users check for updates, or send a notification directly to your users.